# long.TryParse fails when passed a hexidecimal string

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and this test case always fails.
the value of l_sID is 5509df4d0d557e15aca17902. its a hex value and I am trying to match it with long. I know it will fail but what should I do pass this test?

I tried with BigInteger but it was showing error.

> The type or the namespace name"BigInteger" couldnot be found(are you missing a using directive or assembly refernce when I do BigInteger l_lID = 0; instead of long l_lID =0;

```
 BigInteger l_lID= 0;
 if (!BigInteger.TryParse(l_sID, out l_lID))
 throw new Exception("Failed to Upload File ");
```

Comment: You can't use long for alphanumeric sequences...

Comment: Have you checked out MSDN yet? [How to: Convert Between Hexadecimal Strings and Numeric Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)

Comment: Ah thanks. Definitely something new.

Answer (score 9):

> 5509df4d0d557e15aca17902

This hex value is 24 digits, too large to be parsed as a 64-bit integer.

For reference:

- Largest byte 0xFF (2 digits)
- Largest UInt16 0xFFFF (4 digits)
- Largest UInt32 0xFFFFFFFF (8 digits)
- Largest UInt64 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (16 digits)

> I know it will fail but what should I do pass this test?

There is nothing you can do without changing the target data type or the input value.

If you use a smaller hexidecimal number, you need to use the [TryParse overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zbx0k66%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allows you to specify a number style.

```
bool result = Int64.TryParse(stringToConvert, NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number);
```

> I tried with BigInteger but it was showing error.

BigInteger should work fine in .NET 4.0 and later, if you [specify the NumberStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
bool result = BigInteger.TryParse(hexString,
                             NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier,
                             null, out number))
```

> The type or the namespace name"BigInteger" couldnot be found(are you missing a using directive or assembly refernce when I do BigInteger l_lID = 0; instead of long l_lID =0

You need to add an assembly reference to System.Runtime.Numerics (in System.Runtime.Numerics.dll) and add `using System.Numerics;` to the top of your C# file.

Comment: I cannot change the target data type but yes input value can be changed. I tried with bigint instead of long. but it was showing error.

Comment: BitInteger will work if you specify the appropriate NumberStyles.  See updated answer.

Comment: The type or the namespace name"BigInteger" couldnot be found(are you missing a using directive or assembly refernce when I do  BigInteger l_lID = 0; instead of  long l_lID =0;

Comment: Updated my answer to show you how to resolve the error.

Comment: Also, note that `System.Numerics.BigInteger` only exists in .Net versions 4.0 and above.

Comment: i added everything but its still going into exception.